# build error in Xcode. cannot find RCTBridgeModule trying to setup FBSDK in react native

Tags: react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to integrate FBSDK into our app but I am failing with following error [build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhWae.png)

Even if i clone the repo at https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk and try to run the sample, I will still get the same error.

Using FBSDK version 4.x , react-native version 0.38. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Update react-native to 0.40.0

It looks like you are using `react-native-fbsdk` version `0.5.0`. To use that, you need [at least `react-native` version `0.40.0`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/322), due [internal changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e1577df1fd70049ce7f288f91f6e2b18d512ff4d) of `react-native`.

Answer (score 1):

in your package.json file: "react-native-fbsdk": "0.4.0" instead of "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.5.0"

Version 0.5.0 is for RN .40+. You need to use the older version of the package until you upgrade RN.

Comment: can you provide a link showing this versión dependencies?